# Fasted way to load fields from comma separated string

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string like: "ABC, 23, SEE" and correspondingly I have a class named Employee which has properties like Name, Age and Designation.

Now, the string in the example above contains the values in order of Name, Age and Designation. What would be the fastest way to create an instance of the Employee class considering that I have an array of such strings with total number of 100 elements.

Comment: I would just create a PopulateFromCSV method on your Employee class, do your string splitting and population there, 5-8 lines tops.

Comment: Yeah, I was just wondering if there is any faster way of doing this. Splitting and then loading the fields one by one seems to be little tedious considering the large number of data (it could be as much as 500 such strings).

Comment: If you use any library, they will do something like this internally anyways. Why not write those lines yourself?

Comment: 500 strings is not very much. I think you're pre-optimizing. Instead, you should be concerned about picking a solid practice way of doing the parsing.

Comment: based on your string data you can as well consider creating a JSON string and deserialize to your type

Comment: Now that I think over, I think it makes sense to write my own logic to load the fields one by one as you guys said.

Comment: "If you use any library, they will do something like this internally anyways. Why not write those lines yourself?" - because parsing CSV down to the spec is very involved and complicated, such as supporting new lines in a value and supporting quoted values and nested quotes and etc.. It's hard to find specific examples here on SO because every single answer says, "CSV becomes complicated *real fast*; use xx library instead of reinventing the wheel (your wheel will not be as good as the ones already made and optimized and debugged for thousands of hours)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't bother finding the 'fastest' way. You should find '**fast enough**' way. And for 100 strings virtually any method will work fast enough for practical usage. The simplest (the fastest to implement, if we define requirement that way...) would be:

```
var parts = dataStr.Split(new []{','});
var employee = new Employee(parts[0].Trim(), parts[1].Trim(), parts[2].Trim());
```

Comment: Isn't `Trim()` much better than `.Replace(" ", "")`?

Comment: @Quantic, it is, since it doesn't replace spaces between words as well =). But single replace would work faster and consume less memory.

Answer (score 0):

i'd use a CSV mapping library like LinqToCSV. Forgot to add that if you search nuget.org you'll find tons of them.

Comment: Can you give me an example or some reference?

Comment: If you look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library you can see the sample code. It allows you to decorate your Employee class, then read in the CSV and it will do the mapping. there are other, more performant solution as well, all available in nuget.org.